# Android: SurfaceView inside PopupWindow

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, popupwindow

Is it possible to display a `SurfaceView` inside a `PopoupWindow`?

With this XML for the `PopupWindow`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#444444"
    >
    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

the popup doesn't work, and the following log message is generated:

```
W/WindowManager(   60): Attempted to add window with token that is a sub-window: android.os.BinderProxy@4058e3c8.  Aborting.
```

Using `View` instead of `SurfaceView` works fine.

---

**EDIT:**
Seems that the problem is there using platform 2.3.3 but all is working fine using platform 4.1. I haven't tested it with other platform version.